# neo4j rest graphdb hangs when connecting to remote heroku instance

Tags: java, rest, heroku, neo4j

```
public class Test  
{  
       private static RestAPI rest = new RestAPIFacade("myIp","username","password");  
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
              Map<String, Object> foo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
          foo.put("Test key", "testing");
              rest.createNode(foo);  
       }
}
```

No output it just hangs on connection indefinitely.

Environment:
Eclipse
JDK 7
neo4j-rest-binding 1.9: https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding
Heroku

Any ideas as to why this just hangs?

The following code works:

```
 public class Test  
    {  
           private static RestAPI rest = new RestAPIFacade("myIp","username","password");  
           public static void main(String[] args)
           {
                        Node node = rest.getNodeById(1);
           }
    }
```

So it stands that I can correctly retrieve remote values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is caused by lacking usage of transactions. By default neo4j-rest-binding aggregates multiple operations into one request (aka one transaction). There are 2 ways to deal with this:

1. change transactional behaviour to "1 operation = 1 transaction" by setting 
   `-Dorg.neo4j.rest.batch_transaction=false` for your JVM. Be aware this could impact performance since every atomic operation is a seperate REST request.
2. use transactions in your code:

.

```
RestGraphDatabse db = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data",username,password);
Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
try {
    Node node = db.createNode();
    node.setPropery("key", "value");
    tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
```

Comment: why did you use RestGraphDatabase instead of RestAPI?

Comment: because it uses the same API as EmbeddedGraphDatabase. So you can the same code when running Neo4j embedded or as a server (except initialization of [Embedded|Rest]GraphDatabase.

Comment: There is a bug in that version of Java-Rest-Binding that starts internal threads not as daemon threads.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Options above don't work for me and I'm trying to understand where the bug is as per Michael's comment.  Which jar/version has the bug?  
1. Is neo4j-rest-binding same as neo4j-rest-graphdb same as java-rest-binding?
2. OP is using 1.9 of neo4j-rest-binding, but I can't find that version or any versions the github site or maven.
3. Maven has 1.8.1 as the latest version for neo4j-rest-graphdb and is what I'm using with above issue.

Comment: To answer my own questions: The bug is in neo4j-rest-graphdb.jar.  Github has version 1.9 and apparently not available through maven at this time.  The 1.9 code change looks like it could address this problem, but apparently not as per OP.